QGIS 3.38 How to add/join attributes from point layer to line layer begin and end vertex
I have a point layer "my_points" with a field named "Name", and a line layer "my_lines".  I am trying to add the attribute of the nearest point to the begin vertex and the end vertex.  I  researched this issue by using the command "Join attribute by location", but this command only randomly get a value for one vertex.  I tried the virtual layer procedure from
Adding attributes of points to attribut table of lines in QGIS
but could not get a result maybe because the lines are not touching the points.  I tried this other virtual layer procedure from
Joining attributes from points to lines QGIS
and although the new field were populated but it was one value being duplicated. Below is a screen shot of the condition I am dealing with. In this sketch line 1 will have a begin vertex of S-27 and an end vertex of S-37. The next line will have a begin vertex of S-36 and end vertex of S-37.  S-26, S-27, ... S-37 are values from the point layer.


Are you trying to add an attribute value to a vertex of a line - I don't think that is possible.  Or are you trying to set 2 attributes within the line e.g. "nearest_to_start" and "nearest_to_end" which would be set to S-27 and S-37 for line 1?

I am trying to add the attribute to the line layer nearest_to_start and nearest_to_end by taking the value of the point layer.  The point layer has the value.

I used the answer from:
Join point attributes to lines
I created a virtual layer with the following syntax to assign the point attribute to the begin vertex using a value of 10 for the search radius
SELECT My_Lines.*, My_Points.From_Node
FROM My_Lines, My_Points
WHERE st_intersects(st_buffer(st_startpoint(My_Lines.geometry), 10),My_Points.geometry)=1
Then created a second virtual layer with the following syntax
SELECT My_Lines.*, My_Points.To_Node
FROM My_Lines, My_Points
WHERE st_intersects(st_buffer(st_endpoint(My_Lines.geometry), 10),My_Points.geometry)=1
Finally saved these two virtual layers and joined them with the original line layer to create two new fields named Upstream, and Downstream
Another solution will be to use "Vector General - Execute SQL".  The processing is faster than the virtual layer.
